# How to notate a slide in vocal singing

Tags: notation, transcription, articulation, expression

I am transcribing Capella music. I came across singing from D# to B like a slide transcending without steps. How do I notate such a occurrence? Do I draw a line like a guitar slide? Or is there another way to notate this in Capella music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that sounds a lot like a glissando (or portamento --- see [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/what-is-the-difference-between-portamento-and-glissando?s=2%7C40.8427) for a discussion on the difference), I would suggest the following, that is, one line connecting the two notes:

[image: a vocal glissando or portamento]

Also, see [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/34223/32746) for other vocal notation "quirks."